# Tomcat Logs in Host Folders Docker error?

Tags: docker

I like to build a docker with Centos 7 + tomcat 8 + OpenJDK 1.8.212 with logs in a host folder ; I am able to build docker image and run a container out of it with "-v" option mounting host folder. Container is running fine , but no catalina.out and access logs are created and I can see "Permission denied" in docker logs. My dockerfile and docker compose file is as bellow with errors I get.

Part of **Dockerfile**

```
COPY ["keystore", "server.xml", "tomcat-users.xml", "$CATALINA_HOME/conf/"]
ADD ["context.xml", "$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/manager/META-INF/"]

# Create tomcat user
RUN groupadd -r tomcat && \
 useradd -g tomcat -d ${CATALINA_HOME} -s /sbin/nologin  -c "Tomcat user" tomcat && \
 chown -R tomcat:tomcat ${CATALINA_HOME} && \
 chmod -R 777 ${CATALINA_HOME}/

RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "touch /etc/authbind/byport/{80,443} && \
    chmod 700 /etc/authbind/byport/{80,443} && \
    chown -R tomcat /etc/authbind/byport/{80,443}"]

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 433

USER tomcat
CMD authbind --deep /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
```

Docker compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  tomcat:
    hostname: dockertest
    container_name: tomcat
    image: tomcat:8.5.31
    user: tomcat
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /opt/tomcat/logs:/opt/tomcat/logs
```

in my host os /opt/tomcat/logs is created with full permission

```
chmod -R 777 /opt/tomcat/logs
```

docker error logs :

```
10-Jul-2019 03:50:25.923 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
10-Jul-2019 03:50:25.955 SEVERE [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.open Failed to open access log file [/opt/tomcat/logs/localhost_access_log.2019-07-10.txt]
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/logs/localhost_access_log.2019-07-10.txt (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
.......
......
.....
10-Jul-2019 03:50:27.278 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
10-Jul-2019 03:50:27.280 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1412 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just for test, try privileged=true

```
my_service:
  privileged: true
```

Comment: thanks it really worked !. So apart from testing can I use it for production as well, since u mentioned it for "if just for test" , is there any catch in that ???

Comment: I have created a mysql docker instance same as this and mounted datadir, but that was working fine without any issues ; didn't used this "privileged: true"  ; I am so much looking forward to know more on this if u have more details. thanks a lot;

Comment: it means there are other approaches to archive this for "just for test". Because "privileged: true" give container the administrator power to modify the host resource. If we just test something ,we could grant root to the container for a quick verify. Usually, people may use the user mapping to map to specific user to the host, like user jenkins for jenkins slave image.

Comment: I would like to know what are the other different ways I can realise this ? Unless I put privileged=true it won't write into the mounted Host directory. Instead of creating  a Volume I like to mount a host Folder to Container with tomcat user able to write into those dirs. How I can realise it without privileged=true.